# Daily reports from my database

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hello to all I generate daily reports from my database and show them in a table. My code is:

```
<table class="table table-striped m-b-none" id="stats">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    try
    {
    if($_POST["submit"]{
        $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT Date(time) AS date, COUNT(*) AS total FROM branches GROUP BY date;");
        $stmt->execute();
            foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row){
                $date = $row['date'];
                $count = $row['total'];

    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $date; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $count; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
            }
    }
    $conn=null;
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "error  " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The output that I get is:

- 2015/10/26 : 10
- 2015/10/27: 5

But I don't want only the day that i have records, I want all the day of the month. I want my table to be like this:

- 2015/10/26 : 10
- 2015/10/27: 5
- 2015/10/28 : 0
- 2015/10/29: 0
- 2015/10/30 : 0
  etc..

How I can do that?

Thank you!

Comment: somewhere there is a second table. And I suspect you can show us sample data in table format appealing to the eyes for one or two tables. It will be a left join probably

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using date in loop. Use Date as increment.

```
<?php

    // Start date
    $date = '2009-12-06';
    // End date
    $end_date = '2020-12-31';

    while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
                echo "$date\n";
                $date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
    }

?>
```

This will print date from the date you want to start to end date.

According to you code I would suggest you to create a function like

```
function increaseDate($date = null){
   return $date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
}
```

and call it from inside of your loop. Read [Php Date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for date formatting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This prin the dates that I want, but what I really want is:
Chenk in the database for the dates that I have sales.
From the database I'll get [date][sales]. 
So I have a table with one date (11-11-2016). and i want to fill the table with all the dates of the month include the date that I have retreave from the database.